# questions on deploying an applet?

Tags: java, applet

I am using Eclipse to develop an applet module, which requires a bunch of libraries. It runs correctly under the Eclipse environment. I would like to know how to embedded this code in a html page, or how to deploy this applet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a code snippet, something like this will work within an html page to run your applet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <applet height="90%" width="90%" archive="myJavaClasses.jar" code="my/java/applet.class" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the amount of technologies involved in making this work correctly for the end-user, I would strongly suggest that you learn how these things interact well before proceeding.

A good place to start is the [Java Tutorial section on applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) which details how deployment work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- Use [this script](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to avoid compatibility issues.
- Use the good and old [Applet Tag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html).
- Use [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/applet-migration-139512.html).

Answer (score 0):

[There are a number of solutions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html), and depending on your existing web infrastructure, you might find one superior to another.

Generally, in the web page, you add tags (either `<applet ...>` or `<object ...>`) to the document where you wish the applet to be inserted, and the contents of the tab reference the JAR file which the web browser will then download.

Answer (score 0):

> .. applet module, which requires a bunch of libraries.

Add a reference to each library Jar in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.